# Attempt to invoke interface method

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, есть такая проблема:

```
public class QuizFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "CostumeQuiz Activity";
private static final int COSTUMES_IN_QUIZ = 10;
private List<String> fileNameList;
private List<String> quizWorldsList;
private Set<String> worldsSet;
private String correctAnswer;
private int totalGuesses;
private int correctAnswers;
private int guessRows;
private SecureRandom random;
private Handler handler;
private Animation shakeAnimation;
private TextView questionNumberTextView;
private ImageView costumeImageView;
private LinearLayout[] guessLinearLayouts;
private TextView answerTextView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quiz,container,false);
    fileNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    quizWorldsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    random = new SecureRandom();
    handler = new Handler();
    shakeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.incorrect_shake);
    shakeAnimation.setRepeatCount(3);
    questionNumberTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.questionNumberTextView);
    costumeImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.costumeImageView);
    guessLinearLayouts = new LinearLayout[3];
    guessLinearLayouts[0] = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.row1LinearLayout);
    guessLinearLayouts[1] = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.row2LinearLayout);
    guessLinearLayouts[2] = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.row3LinearLayout);
    answerTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);
    for (LinearLayout row : guessLinearLayouts){
        for (int column = 0;column<row.getChildCount();column++){
            Button button = (Button)row.getChildAt(column);
            button.setOnClickListener(guessButtonListener);

        }
    }
    questionNumberTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.question,1,COSTUMES_IN_QUIZ));
    return view;
}
public void updateGuessRows(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences){
    String choises = sharedPreferences.getString(mainActivity.CHOISES,null);
    if (choises != null){
    guessRows = Integer.parseInt(choises)/3;
        choises = sharedPreferences.getString(mainActivity.CHOISES,null);}
    for (LinearLayout layout : guessLinearLayouts)
        layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    for (int row= 0;row<guessRows;row++)
        guessLinearLayouts[row].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
public void updateWorlds(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences){
    worldsSet = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(mainActivity.COSTUMES,null);
}
public void resetQuiz(){
    AssetManager assets = getActivity().getAssets();
    fileNameList.clear();
    try {
        for (String world : worldsSet){
            String[] paths = assets.list(world);
            for (String path : paths)
                fileNameList.add(path.replace(".png",""));
        }
    }
    catch (IOException exeption){
        Log.e(TAG,"Error loading image file names", exeption);
    }
    correctAnswers = 0;
    totalGuesses = 0;
    quizWorldsList.clear();
    int costumeCounter = 1;
    int numberOfCostumes = fileNameList.size();
    while (costumeCounter <= COSTUMES_IN_QUIZ){
        int randomIndex = random.nextInt(numberOfCostumes);
        String fileName = fileNameList.get(randomIndex);
        if(!quizWorldsList.contains(fileName)){
            quizWorldsList.add(fileName);
            ++costumeCounter;
        }
    }
    loadNextCostume();
}

private void loadNextCostume(){
    String nextImage = quizWorldsList.remove(0);
    correctAnswer = nextImage;
    answerTextView.setText("");
    questionNumberTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.question, (correctAnswers + 1), COSTUMES_IN_QUIZ));
    String world = nextImage.substring(0,nextImage.indexOf('-'));
    AssetManager assets = getActivity().getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream stream = assets.open(world + "/" + nextImage + ".png");
        Drawable costume = Drawable.createFromStream(stream,nextImage);
        costumeImageView.setImageDrawable(costume);
    }
    catch (IOException exeption){
        Log.e(TAG,"Error loading " + nextImage, exeption);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(fileNameList);
    int correct = fileNameList.indexOf(correctAnswer);
    fileNameList.add(fileNameList.remove(correct));
    for (int row = 0; row < guessRows; row++){
        for (int column = 0;
                column<guessLinearLayouts[row].getChildCount();column++){
            Button newGuessButton = (Button) guessLinearLayouts[row].getChildAt(column);
            newGuessButton.setEnabled(true);
            String fileName = fileNameList.get((row*3)+column);
            newGuessButton.setText(getCostumeName(fileName));
        }
    }
    int row = random.nextInt(guessRows);
    int column = random.nextInt(3);
    LinearLayout randomRow = guessLinearLayouts[row];
    String costumeName = getCostumeName(correctAnswer);
    ((Button) randomRow.getChildAt(column)).setText(costumeName);
}

private String getCostumeName(String name){
    return name.substring(name.indexOf('-')+1).replace('_',' ' );
}

private View.OnClickListener guessButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button guessButton = ((Button) v);
        String guess = guessButton.getText().toString();
        String answer = getCostumeName(correctAnswer);
        ++totalGuesses;
        if (guess.equals(answer)) {
            ++correctAnswers;
            answerTextView.setText(answer + "!");
            answerTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.correct_answer));
            disableButtons();
            if (correctAnswers == COSTUMES_IN_QUIZ) {
                DialogFragment quizResults = new DialogFragment() {
                    @Override
                    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder.setCancelable(false);
                        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.results, totalGuesses, (1000 / (double) totalGuesses)));
                        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_quiz, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                resetQuiz();
                            }
                        });
                        return builder.create();
                    }
                };
                quizResults.show(getFragmentManager(), "quiz results");
            } else {
                handler.postDelayed(
                        new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                loadNextCostume();
                            }
                        }, 2000);
            }
        } else {
            costumeImageView.startAnimation(shakeAnimation);
            answerTextView.setText(R.string.incorrect_answer);
            answerTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.incorrect_answer));
            guessButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
};

private void disableButtons(){
    for (int row = 0;row <guessRows;row++){
        LinearLayout guessRow = guessLinearLayouts[row];
        for (int i = 0; i < guessRow.getChildCount();i++)
            guessRow.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
    }
}

}
```

вот код ошибки, но я не понимаю как её решить:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.hppavilion15.spidercostumequiz, PID: 9982
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hppavilion15.spidercostumequiz/com.example.Main.mainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.Set.iterator()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.Set.iterator()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.Main.QuizFragment.resetQuiz(QuizFragment.java:99)
        at com.example.Main.mainActivity.onStart(mainActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
```

Comment: `worldSet == null` Вы не инициализируете, или об`null`яете его.

Answer (score 3):

Ну очевидно у вас переменная `worldsSet` не инициализирована, потому что вы метод `updateWorlds` никогда не вызываете.

Comment: Я этот метод вызываю в другом классе

Comment: @МаксимКузьмин, либо вызываете позже, чем надо, либо в `sharedPreferences` этой записи нет и по дефолту вы получаете там `null`.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (preferencesChanged) {
            QuizFragment quizFragment = (QuizFragment)
                    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.quizFragment);
            quizFragment.updateGuessRows(
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
            quizFragment.updateWorlds(
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
            quizFragment.resetQuiz();
            preferencesChanged = false;

        }
    }

Comment: @МаксимКузьмин, ну посмотрите в дебаге, заполняется ли он.